# how to reverse the for loop in python and print the elements from left to right

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code which i wrote in python

```
n = 5
row = 2 * n - 2
for i in range(n,-1,-1):
    for j in range(row):
        print(end="")

    row -=2

    for k in range(i+1):
        print('*',end=" ")

    print()
```

**The output what is get is this**

```
* * * * *  
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

i want to print this start from left to right order for example

**The expected output is :-**

```
* * * * *
  * * * *
    * * *
      * *
        *
```

if it's any possible way to print the elements from left to right because in most of my program i need that logic i'm searching for it please help me and even i used **reversed** function for loop it will reverse the loop but i'm not getting what i expect

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 5
print(*[' '.join(' '*i + '*'*(n-i)) for i in range(n)], sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
* * * * *
  * * * *
    * * *
      * *
        *
```

**Explanation:**

```
for i in range(n):
    chars = ' '*i + '*'*(n-i)  #  creating list of (i) spaces followed
                                   #  by (n-i) stars to finish a line of n elements
    print(' '.join(chars))  # join prepared values with spaces
```

Comment: An explanation would have been fine ;-)

Comment: thanks bro  You use list comprehension  can you give me as i wrote normal code

Comment: I feel like that code is self explanatory but I'll give it a try.

Comment: The code is unnecessarily complicated by writing it as a single call to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution not using list comprehension:

```
n = 5
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(i):
        print("  ", end="")
    for j in range(i+1, n+1):
        print("* ", end="")
    print()
```

Output:

```
* * * * * 
  * * * * 
    * * * 
      * * 
        *
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution - I'm new to python as well:

```
n = 5
c = 0
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(" " * c + "*" * i)
    c += 1
```

or

```
n = 5
c = 0
while n >= 0:
    print(" " * c + "*" * n)
    n -= 1
    c += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `print` itself cannot print right-justified text. But you *can* print a right-justified string instead of using multiple calls to `print`.

Here's your original code, using `join` instead of an inner loop:

```
n = 5
row = 2 * n - 2
for i in range(n,-1,-1):
    for j in range(row):
        print(end="")

    row -=2

    row_str = " ".join(["*"] * i)
    print(row_str)
```

And here's the modified code to make the output right-justified:

```
n = 5
row = 2 * n - 2
whole = row + 1
for i in range(n,-1,-1):
    for j in range(row):
        print(end="")

    row -=2

    row_str = " ".join(["*"] * i).rjust(whole)
    print(row_str)
```